# Add wrapper around block if screen size if smaller than x

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have an image and a text inside it (bootstrap 5, but not relevant)

```
     <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/lib/images/bootstrap-5.0-illustration.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

If screen size is smaller than 800px, text from `carousel-caption` disappears (display:none;), and I would like to wrap `<a href=""> </a>` so people would be able to press on image to proceed. So all text code should become this:

```
<a href="">
         <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/lib/images/bootstrap-5.0-illustration.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>First slide label</h5>
              <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
</a>
```

Not sure if it's possible to do without javascript at all.

Comment: use media queries. Bootstrap also has it implemented as [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Comment: and why not use that `<a>` all the time?

Comment: @tacoshy never knew, that it is possible to add additional html with media queries. Could you give me source ?

Comment: @ITgoldman I had this idea as well, would be simplest solution, but just trying something new. Now seeking if anyone has any idea how to accomplish this without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `.carousel-item` `div` to `a`, remove the `pointer-events` and set the `cursor` as default on screen width >= 800px;

```css
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .carousel-item {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" class="carousel-item d-block">
  <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/lib/images/bootstrap-5.0-illustration.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <h5>First slide label</h5>
    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as below, with comments in the code:

```css
/* simple CSS reset to size all elements according to
   the border-box algorithm, including borders and
   padding inside the declared size of the element,
   whether width, height, inline-size or block-size,
   also removing default margins and padding, and
   setting all fonts to be 16px: */
*,
 ::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* this is simply to show that the media-queries
   are having an effect, and is otherwise entirely
   irrelevant: */
a div {
  background-color: var(--bgColor);
  transition: background-color 0.3s linear;
}

/* here we update the --bgColor custom property,
   as part of the demo to show that the media-
   queries are working, this is irrelevant to the
   functionality; so it can be removed: */
a[data-hidden-by-pagesize] {
  --bgColor: hsl(0deg 50% 90% / 1);
  /* here we use display: contents to position
     the elements as if the <a> wasn't present,
     a pseudo "unwrap": */
  display: contents;
  /* removing pointer-events in order that the
     functionality of the <a> elements is
     prevented (though I don't really understand
     the requirement): */
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* using an @media query, with the 'range' style of
   notation; here we respond to the document width
   being less-than 800px: */
@media screen and (width < 800px) {
  /* then we update the --bgColor property to show
     the functionality of the media-query: */
  a[data-hidden-by-pagesize] {
    --bgColor: hsl(150deg 50% 90% / 1);
    /* setting the display back to its 'default'
       or 'initial' state: */
    display: initial;
    /* and un-setting the pointer-events, to restore
       default functionality to the <a>: */
    pointer-events: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- using the 'date-hidden-by-pagesize' attribute to provide a 'meaningful'
     selector for the relevant <a> elements, obviously adjust to something
     more appropriate for your use-case: -->
<a href="#demo" data-hidden-by-pagesize="">
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/lib/images/bootstrap-5.0-illustration.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h5>First slide label</h5>
      <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ct96kx7e/).

References:

- [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
- [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).